# How to check if LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER is available?

Tags: android, android-location

How to check if `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` is available?

I enabled in `AndroidManifest.xml` but I need to check that in code and if is not available to use `GPS_PROVIDER`. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> How to check if LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER is available?

Use this Part to check whether Network Provider is Enabled or Not :

```
network_enabled=locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

This will return a **boolean** values :

**true**- if enabled.

**false** - not enabled.

additionally for checking if GPS Provider Enabled :

```
gps_enabled=locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

This will return a **boolean** values :

**true**- if enabled.

**false** - not enabled.

If you want the user to Enable Network or GPS Provider use this code to redirect user to Settings Page :

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Comment: The word `enable` seems ambiguous with the word `available` between the question and your answer. I'm also looking for solution to this problem and not really sure if this answer is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

here is the code for getting the location using Network provider and/or GPS provider

```
private Location getLocation() {            
        Location gpslocation = null;
        Location networkLocation = null;

        if(locMan==null){
          locMan = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext() .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
        try {
            if(locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000, 1, gpsListener);
                gpslocation = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            }
            if(locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000, 1, gpsListener);
                networkLocation = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); 
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //Log.e(ErrorCode.ILLEGALARGUMENTERROR, e.toString());
            Log.e("error", e.toString());
        }
        if(gpslocation==null && networkLocation==null)
            return null;

        if(gpslocation!=null && networkLocation!=null){
            if(gpslocation.getTime() < networkLocation.getTime()){
                gpslocation = null;
                return networkLocation;
            }else{
                networkLocation = null;
                return gpslocation;
            }
        }
        if (gpslocation == null) {
            return networkLocation;
        }
        if (networkLocation == null) {
            return gpslocation;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

here it will check whether the GPS provider enable then get the location to gpsLocation if also getting the location using Network provider then check the time which was the fast that location object will return

if one of the provider is enable then that location object will be return

Answer (score 3):

because here its always a little *strange* ;=)

i wrote some own piece of code **to check for network provider availability**:

put this in your **onCreate() Method:**

```
checkIfNetworkLocationAvailable(mContext_);
```

and this **somewhere else in your code** ;=)

```
/**
 * checks if NETWORK LOCATION PROVIDER is available
 */
private void checkIfNetworkLocationAvailable(Context context) {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean networkLocationEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if(!networkLocationEnabled){
        //show dialog to allow user to enable location settings
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setTitle(mContext_.getString(R.string.txtTip));
        dialog.setMessage(R.string.msgLocationServicesDisabled);

        dialog.setPositiveButton(mContext_.getString(R.string.txtYes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
            }
        });

        dialog.setNegativeButton(mContext_.getString(R.string.txtNo), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //nothing to do
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

have fun, hope this helps someone :)
was searching for exactly that piece of code :=)

**cheers :)**